# Combining 2 different queries in flexible search

Tags: flexible-search

We plan to create a delete operation in one of our custom indexers. A document in this indexer consists of several categories and product. When we delete a category, we store it in a new table called SolrDeletedItem. For products, we only set the approval status to unapproved. We want to combine 2 different queries without any relation to get all deleted items stored both in SolrDeletedItem and Product tables. Below are the queries.

- select {deletedItemPK} from {SolrDeletedItem as sdi join ComposedType as ct on {sdi.deletedItemType} = {ct.pk}}
  where {ct.code} = 'Category' and {sdi.modifiedtime} >= ?lastIndexTime
- SELECT {p.PK} AS pk FROM {Product AS p join ArticleApprovalStatus as aas on {aas.pk} = {p.approvalStatus}}
  WHERE {aas.code} = 'unapproved' and {p.modifiedtime} >= ?lastIndexTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT uniontable.PK FROM
(
{{
select {deletedItemPK} as PK from {SolrDeletedItem as sdi join ComposedType as ct on {sdi.deletedItemType} = {ct.pk}} where {ct.code} = 'Category'
}}
UNION ALL
{{
SELECT {p.PK} AS PK FROM {Product AS p join ArticleApprovalStatus as aas on {aas.pk} = {p.approvalStatus}} WHERE {aas.code} = 'unapproved'
}}
) uniontable

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).